# select last affected rows of a table for an immediate select insert into another table

Tags: php, mysql

This is required for a condition based, if Approved or Declined situation. A grid type of form with 25 rows of 30 fields gets submitted for a bulk insert. The last 25 inserted rows will be inserted into a temp_Orders table, then based on the if approve, the same data (last inserted rows in the temp_Orders) need be immediately copied to the real_Orders.

```
$query = "insert into temp_users (fname,sname,lname,email,dob,date_signup,date_expire) values ";    

$count = count($_POST['fname']);

for($x=0;$x < $count; $x++)     
{

    $fname = $_POST['fname'][$x];
    $sname = $_POST['sname'][$x];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'][$x];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'][$x];
    $email = $_POST['email'][$x];

    echo $fname . $sname . $lname . $dob . $email . '<br>';

    $emty_tbl = "TRUNCATE temp_users";

    $result_emty_tbl = mysql_query($emty_tbl);
    if(!$result_emty_tbl){
        die(mysql_error());
        @mysql_free_result($result_emty_tbl);
    }

    $query .= "(
        '$fname', 
        '$sname',
        '$lname', 
        '$email', 
        '$dob',
        '$today',
        '$nextyear')";

    /* If not last iteration, add a comma and a space */
        if ($x < ($count - 1)) {
        $query .= ", ";
    }


    $result = mysql_query($query);


}
if(!$result){
    die(mysql_error());
    @mysql_free_result($result);
} else {

    $totalRID = mysql_affected_rows();
    $lastRID = mysql_insert_id();

    echo "Total records <b>" . $totalRID . " </b>entered into the database!" . "<br>";                                  
    echo "Current record number <b>" . $lastRID . " </b>entered into the database!" . "<br>";
    echo "<form name='postbackid' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' name='lastrecord' value='$lastRID'>
        <input type='button' value='Approved' name='approved' onclick='return Approved();'>
        <input type='button' value='Declined' name='declined' onclick='return Declined();'>                                       
        </form>";       

}   






    }
}



$postbackid=$_POST['lastrecord'];
echo $postbackid;


$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO users (fname, sname, lname, dob, email, date_signup, date_expire)
    SELECT fname, sname, lname, dob, email, date_signup, date_expire
    FROM temp_users 
    WHERE id='$postbackid'";

$resultinsert = mysql_query($sqlinsert, $link);
```

Comment: Could you provide any more information? Why can't the PHP code just keep track of the last 25 rows and do another `INSERT` to the `real_Orders` table?

Comment: for the `mysql_insert_id()` works well, but on `mysql_affected_rows()` fails. No idea how to do this.

Comment: If two rows inserted, the `mysql_insert_id()` inserts the 1st entered row, but `mysql_affected_rows()` only inserts one single last row.

Comment: 1) If $count = 25, you truncate the temp_users table 25 times. Are you sure you want to do that? 2) Are you certain that $postbackid is the same for all 25 of those rows? 3) Are you certain that $postbackid is a string? (Usually, *id* means an integer.)

Comment: both `mysql_insert_id()` and `mysql_affected_rows()` return integers. 1st one returns the last immediately inserted index and the 2nd gives all the rows inserted as one bulk go. This is not the poblem. The problem is getting the total rows inserted in temp for an immediate insert into real table based on the Decline or Approve scenario. How do you get them into an array for insert immediate second insert?

Comment: Catcall: the truncate is before the inserts, so the table empties from previous data and new set of grid data replaces as the last insert rows. It is meant to be this way.

Answer (score 1):

as samimi_it has put it -> mysql_insert_id() will only trace the very last inserted id(uid)
therefore you will either need to:

1. Keep track of the rows within your code - easy way out, but with the highest problems
2. change the way you handle your data, add an additional column onto your temp order rows, like ref/order_no etc and keep that within your code, thereafter if approved simple copy run a query, insert into real_orders (select where order_no = {saved order_no})
3. or remove redundant data by, having one table "orders" 
   include new columns; approved int 0 = false, 1 = true and order_no (to reference the order)
   insert the rows into the orders table with approved = 0.
   then once approved simple do an update orders set approved = 1 where order_no = {order_no_from_code}.

hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Good idea, will try and let you know the result.

Comment: However, I have put the whole scenario into a small example that I can be given for try, including mysql. Anyone interested let me know.